# How to add a keytab for the new flume service that I created

Tags: kerberos, cloudera

I have a hadoop Cloudera cluster with a HDFS service having the kerberos authentication enabled.

I'm creating a flume service owning an agent deployed on an instance of my cluster. I want this role (agent issued from the flume service on the instance), to be able to write on my HDFS service.

To do that, the flume agent needs to have its keytab that will give him the keys allowing him to authenticate to the HDFS cluster.

From the cloudera documentation I read that :

```
At the end of the integration process using the configuration wizard, Cloudera Manager Server will create host principals and deploy keytabs for all services configured on the cluster, which means that Cloudera Manager Server requires a principal that has privileges to create these other accounts.
```

from [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/cm_sg_s3_cm_principal.html)

But after instanciating my flume service I see no keytab in its user folder.

Is there something more that needs to be done to obtain the generation of this keytab ?

Comment: Did you search the Cloudera docs for the **location** of the keytabs? For more context, you assume that a Kerberos principal should be linked to a local Linux account that has a Home Dir -- what about technical "nologin" accounts without a Home Dir?

Comment: From the top of my mind, Horton used `/etc/security/keytabs/` (or something like that) to store keytabs. For Cloudera it's more complicated e.g. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Where-does-Cloudera-Manager-store-generated-keytabs-and/td-p/16314

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter  I found the keytab. It seems that mine aren't identified to the kerberos server. Also my flume user can't access it.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what kind of Cloudera installation you have, but on CDP Public Cloud `keytab`s aren't found in the user directories. They are found locally under `/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process`

From there you pick the most recent folder relative to the service you need. There you will find the `keytab`. Since a keytab allows you to authenticate as a user without knowing its password, only `root` can navigate those folders.